# Woocommerce Menu - Hide one parent category when inside another parent cat

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On one of my sites we offer products and services, and they are all listed in the categories nav in the sidebar. We wanted to separate these so you can look at products or you can look at services, not both.

I wrote some PHP which hides "Services" categories when you are in the "products" parent cat. This also works the other way too, Products cat disappears when you are in Services cat. Code below

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'exclude_widget_category' );
function exclude_widget_category( $args ) {
    

    if ( is_product_category(2921) ) {
    
    $exclude_terms = array();
    array_push( $exclude_terms, 2548, 2245, 2775, 2913, 2846 );
    $termchildren = get_term_children( '2548, 2245, 2775, 2913, 2846', 'product_cat' );
    foreach( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, 'product_cat' );     
        array_push( $exclude_terms, $term->term_id );
    }
    $args['exclude'] = $exclude_terms;
 
    return $args;
}
    else {  
    $exclude_terms = array();
    array_push( $exclude_terms, '2921' );
    $termchildren = get_term_children( '2921', 'product_cat' );
    foreach( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, 'product_cat' );     
        array_push( $exclude_terms, $term->term_id );
    }
    $args['exclude'] = $exclude_terms;
 
    return $args;
}
}
```

On the face of it the code works, selecting one parent cat hides the other. But the issue is that if you then click a subcat it resets and shows all menu items. I was under the impression my inclusion of get_term_children would stop this happening?

Anyone have any ideas or can push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Went about it a different way. Just in case anyone is hoping to accomplish similar i've included the code below.

```
//* dropdown
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'woo_product_cat_widget_args' );
//* list
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'woo_product_cat_widget_args' );
function woo_product_cat_widget_args( $cat_args ) {
    if ( is_product_category( 'experiences' ) || term_is_ancestor_of( 2921, get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat' ) ) { 
   $cat_args['exclude'] = array(2548, 2245, 2775, 2913, 2846);
                return $cat_args;
} 
    else { 
    $cat_args['exclude'] = array('2921');
                return $cat_args;
}
}
```

this is checking if we are on the experiences category or any of its subcats. If we are then it hide all the product categories. Else it hides the experiences cat.